# Optimizing MySql query (IN) to avoid using “Using filesort”

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, filesort

I need your help to optimize the query to avoid using "Using filesort". The query is:

```
SELECT name
FROM actor
WHERE actor_id IN (3333,1452,2587,3003,3044,3524,3700,7087,7088)
ORDER BY name ASC
```

The Explain results:

```
1   SIMPLE  actor   range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 2       9   Using where; Using filesort
```

============================================================

## SQL Fiddle **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c4d/1/0**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `actor` (
`actor_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (7087, 'Brill');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (3333, 'Rey');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (7088, 'Graves');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (1452, 'Phoenix');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (2587, 'Segal');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (3003, 'Taylor');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (3044, 'Daniels');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (3524, 'Michaels');
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES (3700, 'Tryme');
```

Index:

```
ADD INDEX idx_test (actor_id, name) -> EXTRA: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

Comment: do you have a lot more data in that table? when setting up that table with only the data you provide, i only get "using where;using index"

Comment: yes i have more fields like url, thumb, status... but always EXTRA: Using filesort.. (with index, without index).. I do not know why..

Comment: @Marcus-Adams http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50c4d/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use an index for the *range predicate* `IN(...)`. Or you can use an index to eliminate the filesort.

**You can't get both operations to use an index**, at least not when the column in the predicate is different from the column in the sort order.

You created this index:

```
ADD INDEX idx_test (actor_id, name) -> EXTRA: Using where; Using index; Using filesort
```

This helped to find the matching `actor_id` values. And the composite index included the `name` column you wanted. But then you want it sorted by `name`. The index is not sorted by `name`, it's sorted by `actor_id` then by `name`.

*Here's an Analogy to Explain Why This Doesn't Work:*

> Suppose I ask you to look in the telephone book and find people whose
>   last names are Franklin, Hamilton, Jefferson, Washington. Then sort
>   them by first name. The phone book is ordered by last name, then by
>   first name. So you can find the last names quickly, but the first
>   names are returned Benjamin, Alexander, Thomas, George -- not in any
>   sensible order.
>
> To sort them by first name, you'd have to collect the results and then
>   sort them manually. The fact that they were sorted in the telephone
>   book doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always confused why people are so hell-bent on avoiding `FILESORT` !?!

You are asking for a sub-set of a table based on the `actor_id`. The server sees there is an index (PK or idx_test) on the `actor_id` field and will zip through the index to find the relevant records and return them. Now, additionally, you also want the output to be in a given order. Had the order been `ORDER BY actor_id` then it would have been possible to make use of the fact that the fetched records were already pre-sorted on this field in the index (or PK). Thus, no re-sorting would be required and the output could be returned 'as-is' (**).

BUT, you don't want them in order of `actor_id`, you want them in order of `name`. So, the machine does what you ask and sorts the records by `name` before returning them to you. I doubt sorting such a small list is going to take up a lot of resources or time.

PS: I don't think the index helps you much here, in fact it (badly!) duplicates the (clustered) PK. The only (potential) benefit i can see for such an index would be that IF the actual table is much wider THEN it would work as a covering index for this query, reducing the I/O (++). Mind you, this also means you can't ask for any of the other fields when querying.

(**: I'm sure it's all a bit more complex internally)

(++: Less I/O in case of `SELECT`, `IUD` will require more I/O)

Comment: +1, especially for the first sentence. People are hell-bent on avoiding it due to having absolutely no clue what goes on and they come to wrong conclusions.

Comment: @deroby Thank you for your explanation, I thought "using filesort" or "using temporary" is always a bad thing that slows query, so I look for ways to avoid it

(actor table has thousands of records and more columns)

Comment: No worries, "Thousands of rows" should be a breeze for any self-respecting RDBMS.